# Expanding an expression of the form $(a \pm b)^{1/n}$

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

Under what conditions can an expression like the one above (i.e. with a fractional exponent) be expanded? Apparently this kind of expansion is valid in some circumstances but I'm confused as to how given that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\neq a+b$.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can expand $(a + b)^{z}$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ using the Binomial Series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {z \choose k} a^{z-k} \space b^{k}$$
*With the note that $|a| > |b|$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$*

[The Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#cite_note-convergence-11)

Comment: I think you'll want $a > 0$ to reduce complications with choices of branch.

Comment: Doesn't the theorem only apply when $z \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It is generally used with integer values, but it has been generalized to extend to more than just integers.

Comment: Ok, so then (bear with me, I'm a sophomore and haven't done much advanced math; I just got interested in this because I tried to expand an expression in this form in class and got a nonsense answer) can an expression like $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ which $= (a^2 + b^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ be expanded to equal $a + b$? I thought these expressions obviously weren't equal because of the inequality I mentioned in the question but now I'm just confused :/